# Threshold an image using opencv to get same result as imagemagick

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I reached a satisfying solution to the problem I was trying to resolve by thresholding an image using imagemagick and then letting opencv do other stuff to it. However, now that I've reached a satisfying solution, I'm trying to get rid of the dependency on imagemagick.

The way I was thresholding an image in imagemagick was

```
convert image.png -threshold 60% image.png
```

I'm trying to threshold and get same result using opencv like this:

```
    img = cv2.imread(filepath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)           
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,193,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

Although the resulting images look similar to the naked eye, my end results are different.

Is there any way to get the same output using opencv as with `-threshold 60%`?

Comment: From where you got `193`? Maybe a coincidence, but `60%` of `255` is `153` (a possible typo to `193`).

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV, `THRESH_TOZERO` leaves values that exceed the threshold at their original value (see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold%5d), whereas in ImageMagick, values that exceed the threshold are set to the maximum value ([here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#threshold)).

You probably want to use `THRESH_BINARY` instead to mimic the behavior of ImageMagick, but you can browse through the options in the documentation link above to see which one fits your needs.